# Who attributed to King George II the quote "Will someone please remove these infernal chains?"

Tags: american-revolution, movies

The quote is from Pirates of the Caribbean, but I'm certain an author from the American Revolution era wrote something very similar, and hence the irony of the King George II character's quote (although it would have been even better if King George III uttered the line).

Or am I wrong? I couldn't find any references after a Google search.

Comment: @mark-c-wallace Regarding your edits to my question - I would be surprised if George II actually said “Will someone please remove these infernal chains?”, rather I'm asking if a Revolutionary war era author (Thomas Paine?) wrote something similar.

Comment: ?better? I personally found the original title rather difficult to parse, and I was trying to help.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I could have used a few more characters to expand on my question in the title. The gist is whether the movie is making a witty & ironic reference to an American author who was protesting British subjugation, while in the film George II is actually protesting the shackled Jack Sparrow noisily rattling his chains.

Comment: My impression is that questions with complex titles get fewer answers than questions with simpler titles.  If my edits were not helpful, please roll back - I've got no ego at stake, just trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be thinking of the following letter published in the [Boston Post-Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Post-Boy) in December 1773:

> WHEREAS our nation have lately been informed, that the fetters which have been forged for us (by the parliament of Great-Britain) are hourly expected to arrive, in a certain ship, belonging to, or chartered by, the East-India Company. We do therefore declare, that we are determined not to be enslaved, by any power on earth; and that whosoever shall aid, or abet, so infamous a design, or shall presume to let their store, or stores, ***for the reception of the infernal chains***, may depend upon it, that we are prepared, and shall not fail to pay them an unwelcome visit, in which they shall be treated as they deserve;
>
> by  The MOHAWKS.

(my emphasis)

Quoted in [The Military and Naval Magazine of the United States, Volume 5](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6rxLAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA265&lpg=PA265&dq=%22the%20fetters%20which%20have%20been%20forged%20for%20us%20(by%20the%20parliament%20of%20Great-Britain)%22&source=bl&ots=3XNbVfr4Mu&sig=I94t3bAPWnbGxjNUEDPnep1L-DM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG5u_Z0cPXAhWnCcAKHRk9CrEQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20fetters%20which%20have%20been%20forged%20for%20us%20(by%20the%20parliament%20of%20Great-Britain)%22&f=false) p265